# pgsql EXECUTE sql not take effect in version 9.6

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.6

I want to give all privileges to each table in the database。
sql as follows：

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test()
RETURNS void
AS $$   
DECLARE
    tb RECORD;
    sql1 TEXT;
BEGIN
   FOR tb IN (select tablename from pg_tables where schemaname='public') 
     LOOP
            sql1 := 'GRANT ALL ON table ' || tb.tablename || ' TO tmp_admin';
            EXECUTE sql1; 
            --RAISE NOTICE '%s', sql1;
     END LOOP;
END

$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
select * FROM test();
```

when i RAISE NOTICE, it can normal output the sql i wanted。but this sql always effect。

Comment: You don't really need PL/pgSQL or a loop: `grant all on all tables in schema public to tmp_admin;`

Answer (score 0):

> but this sql always effect

I don't know what this means.  Presumably you mean it doesn't do the right thing, otherwise you wouldn't have a question to ask.

As the horse mentioned, you don't to complicate this with a function at all.  But regardless, it does work for me, as long as your table names don't need to be double-quoted.  You should use `FORMAT()` rather than `||` to construct your string, to avoid that problem.

If you get an error, what is the error you get?  If you think it silently has no effect, what did you do to infer the lack of effect?